# Determiner 'some'.

Tags: determiners

Which sentence below is correct and why?

> Some of my friends are married.

or

> Some friends of mine are married.

Thank you.

Comment: ***some*** is a determinative (word class - a member in Parts of Speech family) that acts as a determiner (function) in your second sentence. In your first sentence this determinative act as a determiner, but it lacks a head. This determinative forms a fused determinative phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.  Literally they mean both the same.  The implications suggested by them can differ but in most cases they could be substituted freely for one another.

> Some of my friends are married.

This leans more toward meaning: I have some friends that are married and am implying A) that I have more friends and B) that they aren't married.

> Some friends of mine are married.

This leans more toward meaning: I know some people who are married, they happen to be friends of mine.  I may or may not have friends who are unmarried but I'm not implying anything regarding that.

If a speaker puts emphasis on *some* then it means the same as the first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, and there is no actual difference in meaning. The first might imply a slightly stronger bond between you and your friends. "Some friends of mine" tends to be very general, as if to include acquaintances. But both can be used interchangeably with nothing special implied by either wording.